# Fetch historical intraday data into multiple call with a weekly range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Due to some constraints from my broker, to fetch Intraday historical data the maximum permissible date range in a single rest call is 7 days and any request breaching this range returns an error. So, I need to break the time intervals across various calls to get data beyond this permissible date range. So far, I have split it manually to fetch the data and appending into one data frame.

```
def get_historical_data(scrip):
    data1 = historicData(scrip, "01/07/2019", "07/07/2019")
    data2 = historicData(scrip, "08/07/2019", "14/07/2019")
    data3 = historicData(scrip, "15/07/2019", "21/07/2019")
    data4 = historicData(scrip, "22/07/2019", "28/07/2019")
    data5 = historicData(scrip, "28/07/2019", "31/07/2019")
    data6 = historicData(scrip, "01/08/2019", "07/08/2019")
    data7 = historicData(scrip, "08/08/2019", "14/08/2019")
    data8 = historicData(scrip, "15/08/2019", "21/08/2019")
    data9 = historicData(scrip, "22/08/2019", "28/08/2019")
    data10 = historicData(scrip, "29/08/2019", "04/09/2019")
    data11 = historicData(scrip, "05/09/2019", "11/09/2019")
    data12 = historicData(scrip, "12/09/2019", "17/09/2019")
    data13 = historicData(scrip, "18/09/2019", "18/09/2019")

    data1 = data1.append(data2)
    data1 = data1.append(data3)
    data1 = data1.append(data4)
    data1 = data1.append(data5)
    data1 = data1.append(data6)
    data1 = data1.append(data7)
    data1 = data1.append(data9)
    data1 = data1.append(data10)
    data1 = data1.append(data11)
    data1 = data1.append(data12)
    data1 = data1.append(data13)

    data1 = data1.reset_index(drop=True)

    return data1
```

What will be a good way to split the date range for a one-week interval without doing it manually and return the full data after appending. Something like below:

```
def get_historical_data(scrip, start_date, end_date):

    #Some logic to split the start_date and end_date for one-week interval and fetch the data. 
    #After fetching the data, append into one df. 

    #return appended_data
```

Comment: I suppose you can ```pd.concat``` instead of ```append```, but anyways you won't improve it much, as you still need to call api ```n``` times for ```n``` weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `datetime`, you can offset using `datetime.timedelta()`.  The following function should work for your purposes.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

def get_historical_data(scrip, start_date, end_date):

    date = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end = dt.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

    data = pd.DataFrame()

    while date < end:
        s = date
        e = date + dt.timedelta(days=7)
        if e > end:
            e = end
        date = e +  dt.timedelta(days=1)

        d = historicData(scrip, s, e)
        data.append(d)

    data.reset_index(drop=True)
    return data
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start creating a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) with the first date and loop adding [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta)(days=7) to it until you reach `end_date`